# Add reference to webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl

I am developing a project using Visual Studio 2010, and I need to consume a webservice.  The problem is that the development machine does not have access to the webservice, so I cannot add a reference directly.

What I need is to include a stub in my project that is exactly the same structure like the webservice.  Once I deploy the project on the live server I will then be able to simply change the URL in the web.config and point it to the real webservice.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the webservice wsdl, then execute the Visual Studio command prompt and `wsdl.exe description.wsdl`

This generate a cs proxy file that you can add to your solution and use.

Answer (score 2):

Use [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/concept.html) to mock the services for dev

Answer (score 1):

You can use wsdl.exe to generate your client classes, which you can then add to your project, you will need access to a windows machine on which you can run it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a Visual Studio Web Project with a web service and add it to your solution. After this you can set your reference to Web project and develop with it.